# How to extract data from javascript object using map() in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to extract data from JSON data using `.map()` in javascript. The data extract needs to injected in `stacked bar chart` .

I am trying to do similar to this question : [Stacked bar charts in Chart.js with JSON data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42001984/stacked-bar-charts-in-chart-js-with-json-data?rq=1) but in my case I want total runs per season that will be the height of barchart and the total height of stacked-barchart will be divided into 3 stacks.

check this for stacked bar chart: https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/examples.html#stacked-bar

My JSON data:

```
        const batdata=[
    {"season":2008,
     "runs":25,
     "tournamentName":"XYZ"
    },
    {"season":2008,
     "runs":125,
     "tournamentName":"ABC"
    },
    {"season":2008,
     "runs":825,
     "tournamentName":"PQR"
    },
    {"season":2009,
     "runs":425,
     "tournamentName":"XYZ"
    },
    {"season":2009,
     "runs":255,
     "tournamentName":"ABC"
    },
    {"season":2010,
     "runs":275,
     "tournamentName":"XYZ"
    },
    {"season":2010,
     "runs":675,
     "tournamentName":"ABC"
    }
 ];
    export default batdata;
```

In chart.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import batdata from './batdata';

const uniq = a => [...new Set(a)]

const uniqueseason = uniq(

  batdata.map( newdata => newdata.season)

)

const runsperseason = batdata.map( newdata => {

})

class Chart extends Component {

  render(){
    return(
      <div>    

      </div>
    )}

}

export default Chart;
```

I am using `.map()` to get unique season and then again nested `map()` to get runs for particular season for particular tournamentName. How can I parse the data external json file. The final data should look like this:

```
labels  = [2008,2009 2010]

Chartdata = [
    [25, 125, 825]  <--- Height of barchart = 825+25+125 and it will have 3 stacks because there are 3 tournamentName 
    [425, 255, 0]   <-- tournamentName: PQR not present in season 2009 so 3rd element zero
    [275, 675, 0]   <---tournamentName: PQR not present in season 2010 so 3rd element zero
]
```

I want to extract the data and store it in 3 data in the form of 3 arrays:

```
1)Runs in season 2008 for tournamentName: XYZ,ABC, PQR
2)Runs in season 2009 for tournamentName: XYZ, ABC, PQR
3)Runs in season 2010 for tournamentName: XYZ, ABC, PQR
```

After storing data in 3 different arrays we can just use destructuring operator `...` to unpack array elements and populate the chartdata.

Comment: Your chart data grouping is by **season**, however, in comments you are saying by **tournamentName**. Please clarify on this

Comment: @NikhilAggarwal Check edited question.

Comment: **PQR not present in season 2009 so 3rd element zero** - shouldn't second element be zero?

Comment: @NikhilAggarwal There are 3 seasons and each season haas 3 tournamentName.

Comment: @NikhilAggarwal 3rd tournment name is PQR as XYZ AND ABC are present

Comment: You can't extract ANYTHING from "JSON". JSON is a text format for data interchange. Perhaps you meant you want to extract something from a JavaScript object. If so, say that.

Comment: @torazaburo I have edited question check it out. Did you got my question ?

Comment: @NikhilAggarwal Check the edited question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try following

```js
const batdata=[{"season":2008,"runs":25,"tournamentName":"XYZ"},{"season":2008,"runs":125,"tournamentName":"ABC"},{"season":2008,"runs":825,"tournamentName":"PQR"},{"season":2009,"runs":425,"tournamentName":"XYZ"},{"season":2009,"runs":255,"tournamentName":"ABC"},{"season":2010,"runs":275,"tournamentName":"XYZ"},{"season":2010,"runs":675,"tournamentName":"ABC"}];
 
// Create set for unique tournament names
let tournaments = new Set();

/* Create an object with key as season name and value as object with 
** tournament name as key and run as value */
let obj = batdata.reduce((a,{season, runs, tournamentName}) => {
 a[season] = a[season] || {};
 a[season][[tournamentName]] = runs;
 tournaments.add(tournamentName);
  return a;
 },{});
 
// Create array from set of unique tournament names
 tournaments = Array.from(tournaments);
 
 // Get the labels - seasons
 let labels = Object.keys(obj);

 // Get the data
 let chartData = Object.values(obj);
 
 // Set runs as 0 for missing tournament in the season
 chartData = chartData.map((o) => tournaments.reduce((a,t) => [...a, o[t] ? o[t] : 0], []));

 console.log(labels);
 console.log(chartData);
```

Comment: I am new to `reduce()`. I have few doubts: 1) `,{});` -> this returns an object from `reduce()` is it true ? and 2) Can you explain this `(a,{season, runs, tournamentName})`. Also what is accumulator and currentValue in above code. It would be helpful if you add it in your answer

Comment: @stonerock - reduce return the **accumulator**.  In the above code it is at 2 places - one return an object and second returns an array. Hence,  it can be anything depending upon what needs to be aggregated. In the said code `a` is the accumulator and `{season, runs, tournamentName}` is the **currentValue**. For reference - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Comment: Also, read **Unpacking fields from objects passed as function parameter** section under https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment . I hope it clarifies

Comment: What is this line ->  `a[season] = a[season] || {};` ?

Comment: @stonerock - It means assign `a[season]` to an empty `{}` for the first time as `a[season]` will not exist and then as it exists keep the same value. It is like setting default value.

Comment: I spent almost a day on your answer and now almost everything is clear but if you could explain this line -> `chartData.map((o) => tournaments.reduce((a,t) => [...a, o[t] ? o[t] : 0], []));` I couldn't understand how to `reduce` and `map` works in combination.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172603/discussion-between-nikhil-aggarwal-and-stone-rock).

Answer (score 2):

You can create map to define such filtered object using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```
let filterData = batdata.reduce((filter, value, index) => {

    if (filter[value.season]) {
        filter[value.season] = [...filter[value.season], value.season];
    } else {
        filter[value.season] = [value.season];
    }

    return filter;
}, {});

console.log(filterData)
```

Working [codesandbox#demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/9yrzlkq61o)

Comment: Can it be done using nested `.map()` and `.find()` as I am not familiar with `.reduce()`

Comment: it can be.But reduce is can do things done by map and find and other also array utility.