# How to use reduce() on props in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have made a parent component and child component (Piechart.js). I passed props from parent component to Piechart component like this ->

```
 <Pie batdata={this.props.BattingRecord}/>
```

Above code is in parent component. Now I want to extract data from props inside my Piechart component (which is child component).

When I try console.log(this.props) inside my Piechart component constructor function it shows JSON data in console. See screenshot below:

[image]

Now I want to get the `how` parameter inside `dismissal` see the screenshot above. I think I am not accessing props properly. So what I tried in Piechart component is as follows:

Piechart.jsx:

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react';

    const wickets = this.props.batdata.reduce( (a,{dismissal})  =>{  <--Getting error at this line
        if(!a[dismissal.how]){
            a[dismissal.how]=1;
        }else{
            a[dismissal.how]=a[dismissal.how] + 1;
        }
        return a; 
    }, {});


    console.log(wickets);

    const dismissals = Object.values(wickets);   

    const labels = Object.keys(wickets);  

    //console.log(dismissals);

    //console.log(labels);

class Pie extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    console.log(this.props)
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    const piechart = new Chartist.Pie('.ct-pie-chart', data, options, responsiveOptions);
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
          <div className="col-md-3 col-xs-6 ct-pie-chart">
              {this.piechart}
          </div>
      </div>

    )}

}

export default Pie ;
```

For above code I am getting type error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'batdata' of undefined`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. This means that you should show a `class` along with how its props are set.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice You can see the updated code now.

Comment: What will you do with the value of `wickets`?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I am trying to count the `how` parameter. `how`:`LBW`, `how:CGT`, `how:OUT`. So there are different values for `how` which I am trying to count.

Comment: Yes, I see that `wickets` contains those counts, but you never use these values anywhere in your code. Where do you intend to use them?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice `Wickets` is object with values as keys eg: values are `CGT`, `OUT`, `BOWL` etc. and dismissal is the count of all `how` parameter inside JSON data.

Comment: You have said that several times and you still have not answered my question. You are assigning a variable named `wickets` which is never used, except in a `console.log()`. Where do you intend to use this?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice No I am not using it anywhere. I am just storing key value pairs inside it and then extracting `key` and `value` and assigning it to variable. In my case `key` is `how` but values of `how` are multiple in JSON data which I am counting using `reduce`.

Comment: What is the point of going to all this effort if you don't use the calculated values?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice My `reduce` function is similar to this question -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50712874/how-to-extract-data-from-javascript-object-using-map-in-javascript

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Check the accepted answer of above question.

Comment: So you are just going to `console.log()` the results? Then why do you have a pie chart and why are you using React?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Yes I `console.log(wickets)`. I thought about using `map` but in my case `reduce` is the suitable option because JSON data has `how` but the values are different. So `map` will not count the `how` parameter for particular value. eg: `how:OUT` -> count=2 `how:CGT -> count=5` this is not possible with map that's why I used `reduce`. If you have any better technique which is less confusing and less complicated please suggest :)

Comment: Yes, after looking more closely at your code I see that reduce() is the correct tool, not map(). I still don't understand why you are using React if you only want to do `console.log(wickets)`. Do you want to display these counts in a pie chart?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I am making a React component i.e Piechart component which will display each slice as values of `how`.

Comment: and it took 20 minutes of back and forth for you to finally say that

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Sorry I could not understand what exactly you wanted to know :)

Comment: hope I was able to help. Good luck with your programming

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I just want to ask you, if I had not used `componentDidMount` inside my class then I could have accessed `this.props` anywhere inside class is it possible ?

Comment: Yes, `this.props` is available in any function within your `Pie` class, or any class which `extends Component`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `const wickets` is assigned outside of a class which extends `Component`. You need to move this code inside a member function of `class Pie`. `this.props` will only be defined inside of a class which extends `Component`.

```
class Pie extends Component {
    ...
    componentDidMount(){
        const wickets = this.props.batdata.reduce( (a,{dismissal})  =>{
            if(!a[dismissal.how]){
                a[dismissal.how]=1;
            }else{
                a[dismissal.how]=a[dismissal.how] + 1;
            }
            return a; 
        }, {});
        // Now you can use the value of "wickets" however you wish in this function

    this.piechart = new Chartist.Pie('.ct-pie-chart', data, options, responsiveOptions);
}
```

Even after fixing this problem you are likely to encounter other problems with the pie chart library you are using. If it is intended for use within a React app, you are not rendering it in the correct way.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in your `Piechart` component. The error is quite self-explaining, your `this.props` is undefined. Without `Piechart` component's code, the exact problem cannot be told, however, there are couple of common mistakes that can lead to this error:

- you are trying to access the props inside an event listener which is not properly bound or
- you are trying to access `this.props` inside a stateless functional component or
- inside the component's constructor before `super(props)` is called.

Edited: You are accessing `this.props` our side a proper context, you might want to get some idea how `this` work in JS first: http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascripts-this-with-clarity-and-master-it/ .

To correct your component, you can move the reduce function inside your component class, you can put it inside `componentDidMount` method.

Comment: I could not understand why my component will be correct if I add `reduce()` inside `componentDidMount`

Comment: @stonerock because `this.props` is undefined unless you do so